# R function, multiple If statement form length and art

Tags: r, if-statement, dataset, multiple-columns, string-length

I am quite new in the world of R and I would need your input on an issue I have.
I am making an art project and I want to build the data set in R.
So the goal is to make a function (that is not necessarily precise) that applies a different model from the income of a specific year. Depending on the number of digits there will be a different model. Ex for digits >= 1 then AR model | digits >= 2 then MA model | ext
And I think the problem is with my if statement. The goal is to have a data set with a different  col for all the models

Here is the code for the function:

```
test <- function(x, s){    
  # test set 
  data <- as.data.frame(x)
  # Train set 
  x <- x[0:s]
  # Selecting the years of interests
  time <- 1950:1950+s
  # Pulling the income for a specific year 
  d <- digits(last(x)) %>% 
    # Making sure there's no 0 
    str_replace("0", "1") %>%
    as.numeric()
  # Setting the length 
  l <- length(d)
  # Diff of the data
  dx <- diff(x)

  # Autoregressive Model
 if (l >= 1) {
    d1 <- d[1] 
    e1 <- rep(NA, nrow(data) - (length(x) + d1))
    ar <-arima(x, order = c(d1, 0, 0)) %>% 
      forecast(h = d1)
    ar <- append(x, c(ar$mean[0:d2], e1))  
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, ar))
    names(data)[names(data) == 'ar'] <- paste0("ar", last(time)+d1, sep="")
  } 
  # Moving Average Model 
  if (l >= 2) {
    d2 <- d[2] 
    e2 <- rep(NA, nrow(data) - (length(x) + d2))
    ma <- arima(x, order = c(0, 0, d2)) %>% 
      forecast(h = d2)
    ma <- append(x, c(ma$mean[0:d2], e2))  
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, ma))
    names(data)[names(data) == 'ma'] <- paste0("ma", last(time)+d2, sep="")
  }
  # Autoregressive Moving Average Model
  if (l >= 3) {
    d3 <- d[3]
    e3 <- rep(NA, nrow(data) - (length(x) + d3))
    arima <- arima(x, order = c(d3, d3, d3)) %>%
      forecast(h =d3) # %>% plot() 
    arima <- append(x, c(arima$mean[0:d3], e3))  
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, arima))
    names(data)[names(data) == 'arima'] <- paste0("arima", last(time)+d3, sep="")
  } 
  # Auto Arima Model on diff
  if (l >= 4) {
    d4 <- d[4]
    e4 <- rep(NA, nrow(data) - (length(x) + d4))
      aarima <- auto.arima(dx) %>% 
        forecast(h = d4) # %>% plot()
    dxf <- c(dx, aarima$upper[0:d4,2]) # take upper 95% value
    aarima <- diffinv(dxf, xi = x[1])
    aarima <- append(x, c(aarima[last(s)+d4], e4))  
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, aarima))
    names(data)[names(data) == 'aarima'] <- paste0("aarima", last(time)+d4, sep="")
  }
  # ETS model (Lower 95%)
  if (l >= 5) {
    d5 <- d[5]
    e5 <- rep(NA, nrow(data) - (length(x) + d5))
    ets <- ets(x) %>% 
      forecast(h = d5) #  %>% autoplot()
    ets <- append(x, c(ets$lower[0:d5,2], e5))  
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, ets))
    names(data)[names(data) == 'ets'] <- paste0("ets", last(time)+d5, sep="")
  }
  # AEFIMA (upper 80%)
  if (l >= 6) {
    d6 <- d[6] 
    e6 <- rep(NA, nrow(data) - (length(x) + d6))
    arfima <- fracdiff.sim(100, ma=-.4, d=.3)$series
    arfima <- arfima(x) %>% forecast(h = d6) #%>% autoplot()
    arfima <- append(x, c(arfima$upper[0:d6,1], e6))  
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, arfima))
    names(data)[names(data) == 'arfima'] <- paste0("arfima", last(time)+d6, sep="")
  } 
  # TBATS model (Upper 95%)
  if (l >= 7) {
    d7 <- d[7]
    e7 <- rep(NA, nrow(data) - (length(x) + d7))
    tbats <- tbats(x) %>% forecast(h = d7) #%>% autoplot() # we will be using the upper     forecast 
    tbats <- append(x, c(tbats$upper[0:d7,2], e7))  
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data, tbats))
    names(data)[names(data) == 'tbats'] <- paste0("tbats", last(time)+d7, sep="")
  }
}
```

Comment: In the function, you have some places `ifelse` and some with `if`

Comment: Very true !!! I changed it to only if statements, thank you for noticing!

Comment: I see some issues in the code because `>=1` can also run when it is >=2 or >=3 as there is no upper limit.  You may need to make a & with `& <2`.  i.e. the whenever the value is >1, it runs the first case

Comment: Thank you, I can try that! I am also looking for the code to run all the models, but that the first digit is used for the first model and the second digits for the second model ext

Comment: I think I don't even need the if statement, oh lord... I removed all the If statement and added    assign("data",data, envir = .GlobalEnv)